# How to implement notification service in JavaME - CLDC application?

Tags: java-me, cldc

How to implement notification service in JavaME - CLDC application,for both series 40 and series 60 phones?

Comment: Please Help to find out the solution

Answer (score 0):

could you be a bit more clear about notification service? If you, meant something like doing something when some event like incoming SMS etc. You can take a look at push registry. however, some phones might expect the builds to be signed.

Answer (score 0):

Notification service will be like, if any message/event occurs the notification icon will be changed,clicking it will open the application with the recent updates.
Just like notification service available on desktop.

Comment: It's probably better to add these details as part of your question instead of another answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CLDC or Java ME does not provide you the facilities to do what you are expecting to do.